# How to retrieve compiled TypoScript value for an another page in PHP way?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I would like to get a TypoScript value, compiled not for the current page, but for an another one.

Is there some native API methods for achieve this ?

The best would be something kind of :

```
$foreignTsArray = t3something::getTsArray($foreignPageId);
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to work for me some time ago.

```
$foreignPageId = 999;

$templateParserObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_tsparser_ext');
$templateParserObj->tt_track = 0;
$templateParserObj->init();

$pageSelectObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance ('t3lib_pageSelect');
$rootLine = $pageSelectObj->getRootLine($foreignPageId);
$templateParserObj->runThroughTemplates($rootLine);
$templateParserObj->generateConfig();
$foreignTs = $templateParserObj->setup;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid reinventing the wheel I'd suggest to move the TS to the main level page and enable on both with conditions:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 123] || [globalVar = TSFE:id = 345]
    lib.someSharedObject = ...
[end]
```

Comment: In the module I'm developing, I need exactly what I said : to retrieve the TS data compiled for an another page, nothing to do with TS architecture. Thank You for the participation anyway.